# Start animation with click on item from list view

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-8

How to start animation from list view and also how to make so user can play more then one animation at one time.

I created 3 animations for circle, and list view, my problem is how to position list view so user can clearly see it and how to make it so user can choose one or more then one in same time and play animations from list view. Here is my code for now:

```
    Circle circle2 = new Circle(250, 120, 80);

    circle2.setFill(Color.RED);
    circle2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition();
    fade.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
    fade.setFromValue(10);
    fade.setToValue(0.1);
    fade.setCycleCount(1000);
    fade.setAutoReverse(true);
    fade.setNode(circle2);
    fade.play();

    Circle circle1 = new Circle(250, 120, 80);

    circle1.setFill(Color.RED);
    circle1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition();
    translate.setByX(400);
    translate.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    translate.setCycleCount(500);
    translate.setAutoReverse(true);
    translate.setNode(circle1);
    translate.play();

    Circle circle3 = new Circle(250, 120, 80);

    circle3.setFill(Color.RED);
    circle3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    ScaleTransition scale = new ScaleTransition();
    scale.setByX(25);
    scale.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
    scale.setCycleCount(500);
    scale.setAutoReverse(true);
    scale.setNode(circle3);
    scale.play();

    ListView listView = new ListView();

    listView.getItems().add("Fade Transition");
    listView.getItems().add("Translate Transition");
    listView.getItems().add("Scale Transition");

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2, circle3, listView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 500, 600, Color.WHEAT);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

So yeah, how to position list view so user can see it clear, and how to make list view so user can choose more then one animation and play them in same time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to set the `SelectionMode` to multiple.

```
listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

> You need a listener on the selection model's selected Item property. If something is selected, play its animation. If it's not selected, stop its animation.

```
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->{
    ObservableList<String> selectedItems = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
    if(selectedItems.contains("Fade Transition"))
    {
        fade.play();
    }
    else
    {
        fade.jumpTo(Duration.ZERO);
        fade.stop();                
    }

    if(selectedItems.contains("Translate Transition"))
    {
        translate.play();
    }
    else
    {
        translate.jumpTo(Duration.ZERO);
        translate.stop();
    }

    if(selectedItems.contains("Scale Transition"))
    {
        scale.play();
    }
    else
    {
        scale.jumpTo(Duration.ZERO);
        scale.stop();
    }            
});
```

> You can use a [`SubScene`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html) to contain the nodes that will be animated.

```
hbox.getChildren().addAll(listView, new SubScene(new VBox(circle1, circle2, circle3), 800, 500));
```

> Full code

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.ScaleTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication124 extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {        
        Circle circle2 = new Circle(250, 120, 80);
        circle2.setFill(Color.RED);
        circle2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition();
        fade.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
        fade.setFromValue(10);
        fade.setToValue(0.1);
        fade.setCycleCount(1000);
        fade.setAutoReverse(true);
        fade.setNode(circle2);

        Circle circle1 = new Circle(250, 120, 80);
        circle1.setFill(Color.RED);
        circle1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition();
        translate.setByX(400);
        translate.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
        translate.setCycleCount(500);
        translate.setAutoReverse(true);
        translate.setNode(circle1);

        Circle circle3 = new Circle(250, 120, 80);
        circle3.setFill(Color.RED);
        circle3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        ScaleTransition scale = new ScaleTransition();
        scale.setByX(25);
        scale.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));
        scale.setCycleCount(500);
        scale.setAutoReverse(true);
        scale.setNode(circle3);

        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->{
            ObservableList<String> selectedItems = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
            if(selectedItems.contains("Fade Transition"))
            {
                fade.play();
            }
            else
            {
                fade.jumpTo(Duration.ZERO);
                fade.stop();                
            }

            if(selectedItems.contains("Translate Transition"))
            {
                translate.play();
            }
            else
            {
                translate.jumpTo(Duration.ZERO);
                translate.stop();
            }

            if(selectedItems.contains("Scale Transition"))
            {
                scale.play();
            }
            else
            {
                scale.jumpTo(Duration.ZERO);
                scale.stop();
            }            
        });

        listView.getItems().add("Fade Transition");
        listView.getItems().add("Translate Transition");
        listView.getItems().add("Scale Transition");

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(listView, new SubScene(new VBox(circle1, circle2, circle3), 800, 500));

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 1080, 720, Color.WHEAT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This help me and fix my problem. Thank you!